# API to convert character to a string in C

Tags: c, string, casting, character, atoi

Is there an API to convert a character to a string in C?

I basically have a string and want to insert a character at the end of it.
Say,

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

I want it to look like "hello1";

I am looking for a convenient API instead of something complicated like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
 char str[] = "hello";
 int len = strlen(str);

 /*assume this is the character I want to add at the end */
 str[len] = '1';
 str[len+1] =  NULL;


 printf("%s",str);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char str[] = "hello";` --> `char str[8] = "hello";` will allow 1 extra character

Comment: You want an API call to append a char to a null-terminated char array?  Does nobody write code anymore:(

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char str[] = "hello";
> ```

`str` is an array of six chars: `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, and `'\0'`. When you do `str[strlen(str)] = '1'`, you overwrite the terminating `NUL` character (which is distinct from the `NULL` pointer). When you do `str[strlen(str) + 1] = '\0'`, you write past the end of the array.

Even with variable length arrays, you cannot resize an array once it storage has been allocated.

What you can do is allocate extra space for the string as in:

```
char str[ 7 ] = "hello";
size_t len = strlen(str);
str[ len ] = '1';
str[ len + 1 ] = '\0';
```

Comment: but I wouldn't know before hand, how many characters to append.

Comment: Of course you wouldn't which is why you can't use fixed size arrays with strings which you plan to extend. You need to understand `malloc`, `realloc`, `strcat` etc (especially the problems with `strcat`). One step at a time. My response answers your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for simple way to do it in C, you can use [strcat()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm) function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[8] = "hello";
    char str2[2] = "1";

    strcat(str1, str2);
    printf("%s",str1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but here "1" is a string. I want 1 to be a character and still be able to append.

Answer (score -1):

```
 int len = strlen(str);
```

In this line your size is 6 `('h','e','l','l','o','\0')`.

So, after this line it becomes

```
str[len] = '1';
```

to

```
('h','e','l','l','o','1')
```

and the below line is going out of the array size, so this is not allowed and you cannot resize the array.

```
 str[len+1] =  NULL;
```

what you can do is allocate a larger size array initially

```
char str[7] = "hello";
```